# Conditional table update SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

I want to update table column where value taken from different column of same table, with condition that `CompletionDate='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'`

How can I do it?

```
update Details 
set CompletionDate = (select FixedDate from TblRequirementDetails)
where CompletionDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
and StatusID = '10'
GO
```

produces an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Comment: error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Your subquery is returning multiple rows so you have to filter out the values from subquery. Using where conditions or TOP to get single value whichever satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @CoderofCode How to do that?

Comment: You need to tell me which fixed date you want to select on what basis is it any randome from the `tblrequirementdetails` or there needs to be any condition to select that like matchin any id or somthing like that.

Comment: @CoderofCode if `CompletionDate='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` then `CompletionDate` column must change to `FixedDate` column of same table provided that cloumn `StatusID='10'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unclear on how you want to select the fixed date to set so. By your comments it is clear that you want to set the `CompletionDate` to `FixedDate` of same table when `StausID=10` for fixedDate and I am assuming that It will give you the uniq row.

```
        UPDATE Details
        SET CompletionDate = FixedDate
        WHERE
             CompletionDate='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
             AND StausID= '10'
```

I am including to make sure that The subquery returns only  one row. Bu this is very error prone approch and you need make sure that the Top 1 row is what you want to use.

---

**UPDATE**
As fromm comment I understood as you just want to update the same rows `Complettiondate` with that rows `FixedDate` value so updated the query.

Comment: TOP 1 is not appropriate approach. It must be same row value of column 'FixedDate' where CompletionDate is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query returns many result. Your sub query should only give a 1 value result. See query below

```
UPDATE Details 
SET CompletionDate = (
SELECT 
      FixedDate 
FROM TblRequirementDetails <WHERE CLAUSE HERE THAT ENABLES YOUR QUERY TO RETURN ONLY ONE VALUE>
)
WHERE CompletionDate='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
AND StatusID='10
```